When I submit a form, its not save in the database
I am new to django, I am trying to create an online job portal, I create a model for Job post and a model for application, I create a form to submit the application, admin, everything working, I created a template for the job post and job description and also the application, I used a many to one relationship for the job and the post.
when I create and application in administration site, everything works fine, but when I submitted an application form the viewed template, it doesn't save in the database, so not reflecting on admin site.

class Application(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                    related_name='applications')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='resume/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
        indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['created']),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} apply for {self.job}'

Application view

@require_POST
def apply_job(request, job_id):
    job =get_object_or_404(Job,
                            id=job_id,
                            status=Job.Status.PUBLISHED)
    
    application = None
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # An application was submitted
        form = ApplicationForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            application = form.save(commit=False)
            
            # Assign the application to the job
            application.job = job
            application.save()

    else:
        form = ApplicationForm()

    return render(request, 'jobpost/applications.html',
                                {'job':job,
                                    'form': form,
                        'application':application})

 {% extends 'base.html' %}

 
 {% block title %}
    Apply for this job offer
 {% endblock title %}
    

 
 {% block content %}
 {% if applications %}

 <h2>You have successfully applied for this job. </h2>
 <p><a href="{{job.get_absolute_url }}">Back to the job list</a></p>
 
 {% else %}
 <p>Try again</p>

 {% endif %}
 {% endblock  %}
    


where is the html to render and submit the form?

@require_POST does not seem to make much sense if your view has some path outside request.method == 'POST'.

form.save(commit=False) is suspicious. Generally you want to commit your saves.

@topsail: it is saved with application.save()

it was when I was doing the debugging that I actually made the application.save( ), plural,  I changed it back, still not working

@OlayoriOluwafemiSamuel Please provide complete code. Also share your get method and form rendering html template

Based on your current code I can only assume what can cause the problem. First of all the issue why your form data is not being saved can be due to 2 reasons...

Form data is invalid, you're checking for form validation but in case of invalid data you're not handling the processing. This can cause you to get success response even if form data is invalid and nothing will be saved in database.
Resume file handling in your form. Since you're uploading a file (resume), the form must include request.FILES with request.POST to handle file uplaods through the form.

Here is how you can fix both of these problem...
@require_POST
def apply_job(request, job_id):
    job = get_object_or_404(Job, id=job_id, status=Job.Status.PUBLISHED)

    # Initialize the form with POST and FILE data
    form = ApplicationForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

    # Check if the form is valid
    if form.is_valid():
        application = form.save(commit=False)
        application.job = job
        application.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Your application has been submitted successfully!')
        return render(request, 'jobpost/application_success.html', {'job': job, 'application': application})

    else:
        # Show an error message if the form is invalid
        messages.error(request, 'Oops! The form data is invalid. Please fix the errors below.')
        return render(request, 'jobpost/applications.html', {
            'job': job,
            'form': form,
            'form_errors': form.errors,  # Display the specific form validation errors
        })

I have also removed the if condition checking request method in code as it was not needed since you're already using @require_POST decorator, so it'll make sure that this function only receives post request and nothing else. Hope this solves your issues
